# Spring Mvc Java-based and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am following a course on line about Spring and I have a problem: when I open localhost: 8080/myprojectname I get the 404 error page.
I am trying everything, all the solutions I am finding are not helping me at all.

```
package it.myshop.web;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;


public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {MyShopConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected FrameworkServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        ds.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

```
package it.myshop.web;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.myshop.web.controller")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyShopConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver configureResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("");
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer configureFreeMarker() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer config = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        config.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/view/");
        
        return config;
    }
}
```

```
package it.myshop.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WelcomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Ciao, benvenuto nel mio e-commerce!");
        
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome page!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${message}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

What can be the problem? I'm stucking from weeks and I am not able to find a solution. Thank you!

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! I still don't have a .ftl file, in the course he can start the app and show the contents opening localhost:8080/myprojectname, but I cannot. I run Tomcat embedded in my application (I start it from Eclipse). I am not so expert, so it's hard to explain too, excuse me. That's why I decided to follow the course (a course to be more confused XD).

Comment: Provide link to a course if possible. Also, can you validate, your app is running on port 8080?

Comment: How do you run Tomcat? Do you build your sources into a war file and copy it to Tomcat home directory or you run tomcat embedded inside your application?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a resource (web page) at `/myprojectname`?

Comment: Also: any stacktrace or log output? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get more hints for what information you might want to add

Comment: Is your file located at this path `/WEB-INF/view/welcome.ftl` ?